# Serilog: Request Id implementation

Tags: logging, asp.net-core, serilog, asp.net-core-logging

Lately I have configured Serilog to play nice with ASP.NET Core 2 MVC app and next task is to trace incoming request to web app on every layer of the system. So basically, we want to propagate some token (like `RequestId` generated by Serilog to lower layers of application).

```json
"Serilog": {
    "Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.Console", "Serilog.Sinks.RollingFile" ],
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Debug",
      "Override": {
        "Microsoft": "Warning"
      }
    },
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "RollingFile",
        "Args": {
          "pathFormat": "log-{Hour}.txt",
          "fileSizeLimitBytes": "",
          "retainedFileCountLimit": "",
          "outputTemplate": "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff zzz} [{Application}] [{Level}] [{RequestId}] - {Message}{NewLine}{Exception}"
        }
      }
    ],
    "Enrich": [ "FromLogContext", "WithMachineName", "WithThreadId" ],
    "Properties": {
      "Application": "MultilayerApp"
    }
},
```

In logs we have nice input like

```
2018-01-19 14:06:01.165 +00:00 [App] [Warning] [0HLAV6PIMA9M0:00000001] - Accessing expired session, Key:"6e7f3ab5-db62-335d-1bc7-6824e5b918f5"
```

But my question is where in Serilog is implementation of `RequestId` enricher? Honestly I can't find it.

Answer (score 30):

In ASP.NET Core, the `RequestId` that is exposed by some loggers is the value of [`TraceIdentifier`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.httpcontext.traceidentifier) on the `HttpContext`. This property can be used throughout the application to identify the current request.

For logging purposes, falling back to the `HttpContext` is not the way to go though. The `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging` abstractions support [logging scopes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/) which is a way to provide additional information to the loggers that apply within that scope.

There are two logging scopes that are opened by ASP.NET Core by default. One of those is the [`HostingLogScope`](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/blob/rel/2.0.0/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting/Internal/HostingLoggerExtensions.cs#L96) that is opened [at the beginning of every request](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/blob/rel/2.0.0/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting/Internal/HostingApplicationDiagnostics.cs#L69) (if at least critical logging is enabled).

Loggers can access the information by implementing the [`BeginScope` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.logging.ilogger.beginscope) which gets the `HostingLogScope` object passed to it at the beginning of each request and simply iterating over the object until they find the property:

```
string requestId = null;
if (state is IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, object>> properties)
{
    foreach (var property in properties)
    {
        if (property.Key == "RequestId")
        {
            requestId = property.Value as string;
        }
    }
}
```

Serilog [does pretty much the same](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-extensions-logging/blob/v2.0.1/src/Serilog.Extensions.Logging/Extensions/Logging/SerilogLoggerScope.cs#L65) but stores all properties [in the log event](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-extensions-logging/blob/v2.0.1/src/Serilog.Extensions.Logging/Extensions/Logging/SerilogLoggerScope.cs#L83). That’s why you don’t find an explicit reference to `RequestId` but it’s still there when you specify the logging string format to include it.

Comment: "For logging purposes, falling back to the HttpContext is not the way to go though"  What if you want to log the session ID?  I believe you have to get that from HttpContext.

Comment: @dcp Same thing though; don’t retrieve the HttpContext to just log the information you need but instead expose the information through logging scopes. The `RequestId` is exposed by one of the two default logging scopes but you can always add your own scopes that expose additional values, like the session id.